# Unable to write method in Scala working both for Double and Float

Tags: scala, generics

I'm having trouble to write a method which can be used with `Float` and `Double`. The problem is that I need to multiply my generic type parameter `A` with a `Double` inside my method. It boils down to something like this:

```
 def multiplyWithPi[A](in: A)(implicit num: Numeric[A]) : A = {
    Math.PI * in // does not compile
    num.times(Math.PI, in) // does not compile
    num.times(Math.PI.asInstanceOf[A],in) // does not work (class-cast exception)
  }
```

How can I do that? It's important that return type is the same as the input type

Comment: Implement you own `Numeric` with method `fromDouble(d: Double): A`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`scala.math.Numeric` provides a `fromInt` method, it should arguably also have `fromDouble`. Here is how it would look like:

```
trait MyNumeric[T] {
  def times(a: T, b: T): T
  def fromDouble(d: Double): T
}

object MyNumeric {
  implicit val MyNumericInstance4Double = new MyNumeric[Double] {
    def times(a: Double, b: Double): Double = a * b
    def fromDouble(d: Double): Double = b
  }
  implicit val MyNumericInstance4Float = new MyNumeric[Float] {
    def times(a: Float, b: Float): Float = a * b
    def fromDouble(d: Double): Float = b.toFloat
  }
}

def multiplyWithPi[A](in: A)(implicit num: MyNumeric[A]) : A =
  num.times(num.fromDouble(Math.PI), in)
```

If you feel that type classes are overkill for your needs, you can also go the unsafe route:

```
def multiplyWithPi[A](in: A)(implicit num: Numeric[A]): A = 
  (in match {
    case i: Float  => (i * Math.PI).toFloat
    case i: Double => (i * Math.PI).toDouble
  }).asInstanceOf[A]
```

Or even:

```
def multiplyWithPi(in: Double): Double = in * Math.PI
def multiplyWithPi(in: Float): Float   = (in * Math.PI).toFloat
```

Answer (score 3):

This won't work because `Math.PI` is always a `Double` and never a `Float`. Since the `Numeric` typeclass doesn't supply a value of pi you'll need to add an additional typeclass:

```
trait Pi[A] { def apply():A }
object Pi {
  implicit val double:Pi[Double] = new Pi[Double] { def apply() = Math.PI }
  implicit val float:Pi[Float] = new Pi[Float] { def apply() = Math.PI.toFloat }    
}
```

Then you can do the following:

```
def multiplyWithPi[A](in: A)(implicit num: MyNumeric[A], pi: Pi[A]) : A =
  num.times(pi(), in)
```

Answer (score 3):

The `Numeric[T]` typeclass that is built into scala is pretty basic. If you want to do something a bit more advanced with math in scala, I suggest using the [spire](https://github.com/non/spire) math library.

Here is how you would implement the function in spire:

```
import spire.algebra._ // algebraic typeclasses
import spire.implicits._ // syntax and instances

def multiplyWithPi[A: Ring: Trig](x: A) : A = {
  Trig[A].pi * x
}
```

Here is how it works: The `Ring[T]` typeclass is for types that allow multiplication. The `Trig[T]` typeclass is for types that allow trigonometry. In addition to trigonometric function such as sin, it also comes with values `pi` and `e`.

Note that this approach does *not* rely on converting from the imprecise double approximation to T you can find in `Math.PI`. E.g. spire has several number types for exact arithmetic. For those, converting from a double approximation would be very imprecise.

The `spire.algebra._` import is for all typeclasses, including `Trig[T]` and `Ring[T]`. The `spire.implicits._` import provides predefined typeclass instances for `Float` and `Double`.

To use spire, add the following to your build.sbt:

```
libraryDependencies += "org.spire-math" %% "spire" % "0.13.0"
```